# How to clear session and cache of Safari using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, safari, selenium-webdriver

I want to clear session of `Safari`using `Selenium WebDriver` with `Ruby`

I have tried following code. Which I found here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Safari::Options.new
opts.clean_session = true
```

but it is giving me error saying

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `clean_session=' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Safari::Options:0x007f9a8a912568>
```

We can use clean_session? method which returns boolean value.
So is there any other way to clear session and clear cache of Safari using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Ruby Doc have a method clean_session here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings But, I didn't find method here http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/method_list.html  Please try "delete_all_visible_cookies" or "delete_cookie(name, optionsString)"